# compile error: Method or data member not found when using CountIf

Tags: excel, vba

I need to count the number of "B" when the text 'CS55" and "B" are present in column K
However this part of the code is giving me the error message

```
If Cells(lrNew, "K").Value Like "*CS55*" Then
 n = ws1.CountIf(Range(lrNew, "K"), "*B*")
End If
```

full code below

```
Sub PaintCS55()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, lrNew As Long, n As Long, n1 As Long, n2 As Long
lrNew = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
sr = 2

If Cells(lrNew, "K").Value Like "*CS55*" Then
 n = ws1.CountIf(Range(lrNew, "K"), "*B*")
End If

If Cells(lrNew, "K").Value Like "*CS55**Black*" Then
     n1 = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Range("C" & sr & ":C" & lr), Range("K" & sr & ":K" & lr), "*CS55**Black*")
     n2 = n1 * 0.000666 * 7.48 * 2
End If
If Cells(lrNew, "K").Value Like "*CS55*" And _
   n = 1 Then
     n1 = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Range("C" & sr & ":C" & lr), Range("K" & sr & ":K" & lr), "*CS55**B*")
     n2 = n1 * 0.000666 * 7.48
End If
If Cells(lrNew, "K").Value Like "*CS55*" And _
   n = 2 Then
     n1 = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Range("C" & sr & ":C" & lr), Range("K" & sr & ":K" & lr), "*CS55**B*")
     n2 = n1 * 0.000666 * 7.48 * 2
End If

lrNew = lrNew + 1
Cells(lrNew, "A") = Cells(lr, "A")
Cells(lrNew, "B") = "."
Cells(lrNew, "C") = n2
Cells(lrNew, "D") = "F62655"
Cells(lrNew, "I") = "Purchased"
Cells(lrNew, "K") = "CS55 Black"
If Cells(lrNew, "C").Value Like "*0*" Then
    Rows(lrNew).Delete
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Why use WorksheetFunction for SumIfs but not for CountIf?

Answer (score 0):

When using Excel formulas in VBA you have 2 options.

1. Use the Worksheet.WorksheetFunction object

```
n = ws1.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(lrNew, "K"), "*B*")
```

2. Call Evaluate()

```
'Used the index 11 instead of K to reference the column to avoid using quotes
'In a string, first quote of 2 consecutive quotes is an escape character 
n = Evaluate("COUNTIF(" & cells(lrNew, 11).Address & ",""*B*""")
```

Also if you are counting the instances of B in a string CountIf won't work as CountIf only counts cells in a range. The easiest way is to take the difference between the length of the string and the length of the string with Bs removed. When nesting formulas I prefer to use Evaluate() which would look like:

```
n = Evaluate("LEN(" & cells(lrNew, 11).Address & ")-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(" & cells(lrNew, 11).Address & ",""B"","""")")
```

You can also store the cell address in a string to make the above more readable.

```
Dim adr as String
adr = cells(lrNew, 11).Address
n = Evaluate("LEN(" & adr  & ")-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(" & adr  & ",""B"","""")")
```

Comment: Thanks Rev, I love the idea of taking the difference in length after taking out "B". Thanks for correcting me on the CountIf method.

Comment: after I modified my code, I got an error message "Type mismatch". Not sure why this error poped up, because the excel file I used for testing has CS55 and "B" in the same cell.

Comment: I realized I forgot a closing bracket in the Evaluate statements after the first LEN, that should fix the Type Mismatch. The Type Mismatch in this case is because there was an error in the formula passed to Evaluate, so it would return an error that cannot be stored in a variable that was declared an integer.

Comment: Note that Worksheet.WorksheetFunction and [Application].Evaluate are not equivalent: one operates in the context of a specific worksheet, the other operates in the context of whatever the ActiveSheet is. Implicitly referring to the ActiveSheet is an extremely common source of bugs. Worksheet.Evaluate would do though.

Comment: Wait isn't it _Application_.WorksheetFunction?

Comment: Like This ?  There is still a mismatch somewhere :(                                                               n = ws1.Evaluate("LEN)(" & Cells(lrNew, 11).Address & "-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(" & Cells(lrNew, 11).Address & ",""B"","""")")

Comment: I tried to use Worksheet.Evaluate, and ws1.Evaluate, there is always a mismatch somewhere. @MathieuGuindon

Comment: the format of the text string is pretty consistent: CS55,B/R/B, CS55,B/W, CS55,B/G/R, CS55,R/G/B, CS55,B/G...etc There is always a comma after CS55, before the part of the string that contains B.